# Sometimes bot can't mention user by id

Tags: telegram-bot

I am writing an address book bot for my company group chat.
The main idea of the bot is an ability to search users telegram contacts. For example `/find <first name & last name>` search bot's database and reply **mention** of a founded user, so people can contact with that person, clicking on its mention (via `[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)`).
The problem is sometimes bot get `ENTITY_MENTION_USER_INVALID`. Furthermore, after few minutes, mention of that user can be successful.
As a workaround, I try to use @userName instead of mentions by userId, but now I have another trouble: not all the people have @userName.
So the question is: *How to avoid `ENTITY_MENTION_USER_INVALID` error?*

Comment: It's possible that you sent a sample chat_id like 123456789. If you use of real chat_id the problem may be gone.

Comment: @ZoeGraystone Sure, I use real chat_id. It works **occasionally**

Comment: Dear @RoninDev, Would you please share a ChatId that have make problem more than other for test?

Comment: You can't mention a user that hasn't communicated with that bot

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options):

> These mentions are only guaranteed to work if the user has contacted
>   the bot in the past or is a member in the group where he was
>   mentioned.

You can only mention users that at least started the bot.